# Query URL for getting JSON response based on subelement

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, api, rest

I´ve got an API which uses mongodb and returns data in form of JSON. Turns out I want to query the data I get in the offers path which returns a list of offers.
Each offer contains its id, a request which is a nested element, an user which is also a nested element.

I want to query the offers so that I only get the offers made by the user with email test@mail.com for example.

So I'd like to do something like https://myapi.com/offers?user.email=test@mail.com.
However that does not work.

Here's the response for https://myapi.com/offers?_id=abc:

```
{
  "_id":"abc",
  "request":{
       "_id":"abc",
       "amount":5,
       "good":"Mouse",
       "institution":{
            "_id":"555",
            "address":"xx",
            "description":"Generar un entorno protector donde los niños puedan desarrollarse, ayudando a las familias para que esto se haga realidad.",
            "email":"testtt",
            "name":"Aldeas Infantiles SOS",
            "phone":"177",
            "referent":"Mauricio",
            "status":true,
            "createdAt":"2019-03-22T22:47:58.201Z",
            "updatedAt":"2019-06-11T18:33:16.543Z",
            "__v":0,
            "category":"Alimentación infantil"
       },
       "createdAt":"2019-03-27T12:46:14.348Z",
       "updatedAt":"2019-03-27T12:46:14.348Z",
       "__v":0
  },
  "amount":2,
  "timeframe":[
      {
       "day":"MONDAY",
       "time":"MORNING",
       "_id":"579c6547",
       "createdAt":"2019-04-25T23:52:56.027Z",
       "updatedAt":"2019-04-25T23:52:56.027Z"}
  ],
  "user":{
      "category":"Quiero ser Voluntario",
      "_id":"5cc24002c05580001743c013",
      "address":"Av Las Heras ",
      "email":"testmail",
      "name":"[donante] Juan",
      "phone":"1107",
      "surname":"Perez",
      "createdAt":"2019-04-25T23:17:22.084Z",
      "updatedAt":"2019-05-28T21:51:55.762Z",
      "__v":0
  },
  "comments":"",
  "good":"Mouse",
  "createdAt":"2019-04-25T23:52:56.028Z",
  "updatedAt":"2019-04-25T23:52:56.028Z",
  "__v":0
}
```

As you that filter works fine but that´s not what I want.
I want to get the offers filtered by user.email.
What route or path should I use??

Update:

From the API code, this method is called:

```
// Retrieve and return all offers from the database.
exports.findAll = (req, res) => {
    Offer.find(req.query)
    .populate({
      path: 'request',
      populate: {path: 'institution'}
    })
    .populate('user')
    .then(offers => {
        res.send(offers);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving offers."
        });
    });
};
```

And the schema:

```
const OfferSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    amount: { type: Number, required: true, min: 1},
    good: String,
    request: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Request'},
    timeframe: [TimeframeSchema],
    user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    comments: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Offer', OfferSchema);
```

Comment: Is that object the way the documents are stored in the collection?  What query are you executing?  Can we see the query code?

Comment: @Joe Sorry, I just updated my question.

Comment: You can filter the documents while populating.  Check out the populate docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions